# Saving objects to an array and printing stored object data

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I have this method created to ask a user to input job details, and save to an array:

public static void addJob() {
currentJobIndex = 0;

```
    jobs[currentJobIndex] = new Job();
    jobs[currentJobIndex].getInformation();
    jobs[currentJobIndex].calculateCost();
    jobs[currentJobIndex].display();
    jobs[currentJobIndex].getCostTotal();
    currentJobIndex++;
```

I have this method to display all jobs saved in the array:

public static void showAllJobs() {

```
    for (Job job : jobs) {
        if (job != null) {
            job.display();
        }
    }

}
```

It is only showing the last entered job and I cant figure out why, any assistance would be appreciated!

Comment: When you use the `addJob()` method you have `currentJobIndex = 0;` so items will only ever be inserted al position 0 (and will overwrite anything else that was there). You need to increment this number and ensure that your array has space. You should probably be using an ArrayList that already has an add method.

Comment: Thank you, removing the currentJobIndex = 0; resolved the issue!

Answer (score 0):

This is because every time you call the method, `currentJobIndex = 0;` is executed again, so you do not go to the next position in the array, but always write to `jobs[0]`. `currentJobIndex` needs to be a global variable, like this:

```java
public class Job(){
   private int[] jobs = new int[5]; // Specify length of array here.
   private currentJobIndex = 0;

   public void addJob(){
    jobs[currentJobIndex] = new Job();
    jobs[currentJobIndex].getInformation();
    jobs[currentJobIndex].calculateCost();
    jobs[currentJobIndex].display();
    jobs[currentJobIndex].getCostTotal();
    currentJobIndex++;
   }
}
```

(Sidenote: Since you probably don't know how many jobs will be stored in advance, a list would be the better choice here.)

Answer (score -1):

This is because currentJobIndex doesn't increment when you add a new job.

You can fix this by adding:

```
public static void addJob() { currentJobIndex = 0;

    jobs[currentJobIndex] = new Job();
    jobs[currentJobIndex].getInformation();
    jobs[currentJobIndex].calculateCost();
    jobs[currentJobIndex].display();
    jobs[currentJobIndex].getCostTotal();

    currentJobIndex++;

     }
```

Comment: This will not solve the problem. `currentJobIndex` will still be set to 0 every time the method is called.